# add custom header for checkout page in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I want add a custom header for my checkout page of opencart store.
I have a website in opencart store and I don't want to show categories and search button at my checkout page as user already ready for shop now he didn't need of categories and search button. So I think I can do it ny make a copy of header.tpl file and rename it and call a variable at checkout page as the previous one php echo $header with the new renamed file. but it showing error could you please let me know how to add custom header for checkout page.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: and what version of open cart you are using?

Comment: I am using opencart 1.5.6.4.

Comment: what error you are getting tell me exact and show me your code sample so i can judge the issue, this is not a big issue it seems you are missing something.

Comment: and when I copy header.tpl file and rename it to header_copy.tpl and change the <?php echo $header_copy; ?> in my checkout.tpl file I found the following error  Undefined variable: header_copy in C:\wamp\www\5\catalog\view\theme\pav_wine\template\checkout\checkout.tpl on line 1

Comment: and if I change the header from header_copy in controller/checkout/checkout.php file in the array                                            $this->children = array(
   'common/column_left',
   'common/column_right',
   'common/content_top',
   'common/content_bottom',
   'common/footer',
   'common/header' 
  );                                                                                                     then I found this error Fatal error: Class 'Controllercommonheadercopy' not found in C:\wamp\www\5\system\engine\controller.php on line 41 but nothing in the file to be correct

Comment: no no you are doing wrong, you must also copy header.php and make it header_copy.php and then call in your checkout page. so you have to make copies or header.tpl and controller/common/header.php also and then call in your checkout page.

Comment: I copy header.php file in controller/common/header.php and rename it to header_copy.php file and also I change the header into header_copy inside the file. but same error of undefined variable I found.

Comment: i gave you full answer, follow these steps and then let me know issues is resolved or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make any changes to the header.tpl file.
Instead write your custom code into checkout.tpl file in the template/checkout folder.
Replace the $header with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some steps if you are doing like make copies of header files then you have to make copies of all header related files.

Make Copy of header.tpl and make it headercopy.tpl then make copy of controller/common/header.php to headercopy.php.

then change on line 2 in headercopy.php

```
Controllercommonheader
```

with

```
Controllercommonheadercopy
```

then call in checkout.php following  array

```
    $this->children = array( 'common/column_left', 
'common/column_right', 
'common/content_top', 
'common/content_bottom', 
'common/footer', 
'common/headercopy' );
```

and then in your checkout.tpl file call

```
<?php echo $headercopy; ?>
```